# How much magic can DBIx::Class::Row::set_columns do?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

Is [DBIx::Class::Row::set_columns](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.082820/lib/DBIx/Class/Row.pm#set_columns) clever enough to update prefetched child rows?

I've tried it, and it doesn't seem to be.  I'm probably expecting too much magic.

I did something like this:

```
my $data = {
    id => 1,
    date => '2015-06-27',
    # etc.
    invoice_lines => [{
        id => 101,
        # etc.
    ]},
};
my $rs = $schema->resultset('Invoice')->search(
    { 'me.id' => $id },
    { prefetch => 'invoice_lines' },
)->first;
$rs->set_columns($data);
```

and got something like this:

```
SELECT me.id, me.date, ..., invoice_lines.id, ... FROM invoices me LEFT 
JOIN invoice_lines invoice_lines ON invoice_lines.invoice_id = me.id WHERE ( me.id = ? ) ORDER BY me.id: '1'
Mojo::Reactor::EV: Read failed: DBIx::Class::Row::get_column(): No such column 'invoice_lines' on MyProg::DB::Schema::Result::Invoice at /home
/chris/stuff/Invoices.pm line 289
```

It thinks 'invoice_lines' is just another column, rather than a relationship.  The relationships are working properly when inserting into or reading from the database, so I haven't included all the gory details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature isn't core although it is planned.
Currently there is the [DBIx::Class::ResultSet::RecursiveUpdate](https://metacpan.org/release/DBIx-Class-ResultSet-RecursiveUpdate) module that implements this.